# OpenId Connect Implicit flow, how to maintain session

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, okta, okta-api

I am building an Angular SPA app and using Okta as an Idp. since its an SPA so I think I need to use Implicit flow. I have two queries here-

1. Since in Implicit flow a refresh token is not issued, does it means that th user will be logged out of the app after the token expires and he has to log in again?
2. Why do I need to use Implicit flow in case of SPA? why not Authorization code flow? since I have control over both the front end (SPA) and back end (REST API) . for example in case of Spring MVC architecture for the web app  Authorization code flow is possible.

Thanks,
pchh

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, if the token expired, you have to re-autenticate. Normally you still have a valid session on the identity providers site, so you can do a "silent" login using an iframe. Libraries like `oidc-client` support a `silent login`, which can do this for you.
2. You need to use implicit (or hybrid) flow, when you need to access to the access token from your javascript app. With authorization code flow your javascript app doesn't get the access token, so if your API needs an access token for authorization, what are you going to send?

Comment: Thanks @mode777.    1.  so if a user is active then too does the token expires?
 i.e. suppose the lifetime of token is 10 minutes and the user is active for all 10 minutes, is't it strange that that he has to re-authenticate before 10 minutes , which means the library has to keep track and get a new token before 10 minutes           2. Cant I make an HTTP call from the javascript and parse the header and get the authorization token

Comment: The OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token spec says that lifetimes up to 60 min are ok ([section. 5.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750)). But yes, eventually your token will expire. As @Ján Halaša and me described, you can silently get a token in the background, if you still habe a SSO session, once your session expires. I will try to add an example using `oidc-client`

Comment: @mode777 does the renewal rely on cookies? If so, it may not work if the idp site used in the renewal iframe is hosted on another domain and browser has disabled "Third Party Cookies"

Comment: @akn I don't think Third Party Cookies will be a problem here. Yes cookies are involved here but only First Party Cookies. The silent renew relies on an iframe to the SSO provider's login page. If in the context of the Iframe a user still has a cookie with a valid session, silent renew can occur. So there are no cookies stored on your client application but only at the SSO provider.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your auth server supports OpenID Connect (OAuth2 extension) and single sign-on (SSO) feature, to get a new token before the old gets expired, use an `iframe` with a URL you used for authentication, but add `prompt=none` parameter (and possibly `id_token_hint` parameter). See [OpenId Connect RFC](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest). The `prompt=none` parameter tells the `/auth` endpoint to issue a new token(s) if the user has an open SSO session at your OAuth2 server. If not, the request will fail. There is a separate RFC for [session management](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html).
2. The Authorization code flow requires you to access the `/token` endpoint, which usually requires authentication (client ID + client secret) and you cannot keep the secret safe in a browser. For this reason, the token endpoint doesn't use to support CORS headers, so you cannot access it using XHR. Using the Auth code flow, you get a code as a redirect URL param (`?code=`), which gets to the server hosting your SPA (browser sends it there after redirect). The implicit flow returns tokens in hash part of the redirect URL (`#access_token=`), which stays in a browser (it's not sent to the server), so it's safer.

Comment: I wouln't say that it is safer if the access token stays in the browser. The purpose of some flows is to actually prevent passing the token to the browser. However, in the case of a single page app, there often is no server-side of the client so you need to manage the token in the browser.

Comment: Thanks @Ján Halaša. so to support Authorization code flow cant the javascript make an http request to authorization end point and get the redirect url and parse and fetch the code and send it to SPA and then SPA access the /token endpoint as it would normally do

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you want to have a backend that exchanges a code for tokens and sends the tokens to your SPA, yes, you could do it like that, but I think the Implicit flow was created for you not needing to do such things.

Comment: Oh ok. there was typo error I have corrected it below.

Comment: so to support Authorization code flow cant the javascript at SPA make an http request to authorization end point and get the redirect url and parse and fetch the code and send it to Service provider or BackEnd and then Service provider or BackEnd access the /token endpoint as it would normally do

Comment: Thanks @Ján Halaša. I mean't, suppose I have a classical web app using Spring MVC where back end works as an Service Provder, and if I want to change front end from JSP to more modern Angular SPA, will  Angular also able to do the same thing as JSP/HTML was doing earlier w.r.t Authorization code flow